# While loop stopped working

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
# set the Internal Field Separator to a pipe symbol
IFS='|'

# file name
file=/backup/diskonly_backupfiles/EMPTORIS_ACE/LATEST/Batch1/contract.txt

# use while loop to read domain and ip 
while read contract dmsuuid
do
    print "$contract has contract $dmsuuid"
done <"$file"
```

Above is the script and it is not displaying anything

Answer (score 0):

Is the input file, "contract.txt" readable?  Can you use the "more" command to view it:

```
$ more $file
```

Comment: when i do  more $contract.txt i m getting 30075.txt: No such file or directory error.   but the file has 30075|364db2b56fbd4d53a5d940d1d89aa82c, when i view the file i can see this. please  help me. the while loop was working and suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Ok, since you did the

 more $contract.txt

command, and you get the no such file on 30075.txt, this indicates that the while loop must have read the file, such that $contract became "30075".  

I've tried this on my machine, and it works fine.  So, it's probably something in your environment has changed to cause this to stop working.

I would log out and login again to see if that fixes it.  If it does, then you may have something like an alias for "print" that keeps it from doing what it should.  Or, you may have your stdout redirected elsewhere.  Or, something else is going on.

Comment: thank you that worked